# Deployed Qt application does not list available printers

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, printing, qprinter

When deploying an application with Qt, the list of available printers is not showing. Dependency walker did not report any problems.

Comment: The dependency walker doesn't know about Qt plugins, so if a Qt application starts up at all, the dependency walker is useless from that point onwards :(

Answer (score 0):

The plugin printsupport has to be supplied together with the deployed application.

Go to: C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\plugins (or whereever you installed Qt) and find the printsupport folder. Copy this folder to the same location as your exe.